# Validate account and get permissions

Tags: java, pingfederate

I trying to implement simple console application.
I have login and password an want to validate that user with such password exist in PingFederate and get list of his permissions.

I found that PingFederate implement WXTrust spec, but unable to find any examples of its usage.

PS: I'm not constrained with using WXTrust, if there is other way to solve my problem I will be more than happy to hear about it.

Comment: PingFederate doesn't have users. Users exist in repositories (generally an LDAP directory) behind PingFed... Is that what you're trying to do? You should reach out to your account's RSA (Regional Solutions Architect) to thoroughly talk through what it is that you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I understand that PingFederate do not store information about users itself, but my underlying source isn't accessible from host where I want to run my application. I suppose that if PingFederate can authenticate users it should be able to provide that functionality thru some API.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your response, the only functionality available to you will be WS-Trust, using the Username Token Processor (built into versions 8.0+, or additional download for versions lower). There is no user validation API, beyond the SOAP WS-Trust methodology.

You'll need to build a standards-compliant WS-Trust RST providing username/password, and receive an RSTR from PingFed. Our RSAs can provide supported customers with sample code for .net and Java to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

One other approach to consider is OAuth 2.0. It offers a simpler HTTP based interaction (compared to WS-Trust) that can be used to authenticate and authorize a user's access to an application.

If your need is username/password validation (not via a browser, but based on user input in your app) then the resource owner password grant type would be most appropriate.

More information on it (and other OAuth flows) is available on Ping Identity's developer site here: https://www.pingidentity.com/content/developer/en/resources/oauth-2-0-developers-guide.html#ropc